# extra steps in printf function in assembly language

Tags: assembly, stack

Original Code:

```
void main()
{
    int x = 1;
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

The corresponding assembly code is:

```
   |0x80483f5 <main+17>     mov    $0x80484e0,%eax
   │0x80483fa <main+22>     mov    0x1c(%esp),%edx
   │0x80483fe <main+26>     mov    %edx,0x4(%esp)
   │0x8048402 <main+30>     mov    %eax,(%esp)
   │0x8048405 <main+33>     call   0x8048300 <printf@plt>

It first moves the string "%d\n" in %eax          ---->Extra Step
Then it moves the value of 0x1c(%esp) in %edx     ---->Extra Step
```

Then these two values are placed in top of stack for a standard procedure call i.e. call to printf()

My question is that why the two extra steps ? Why can't it simply get those values from the memory and keep it directly in stack instead of using the two registers ?

Comment: Is the assembly much different if you compile with all optimizations turned on (assuming you aren't already)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x86 architecture doesn't have a `mov` instruction (except for `movs` but that's not relevant here) that can copy from memory to memory which is why the code uses registers to temporarily store the arguments while they are copied to the stack.

Note that `push` can be used with a memory operand, but presumably the stack pointer has already been adjusted to allocate space for the arguments.